# azure web sites and VM in the same data center

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure VM with a database. I also have azure web sites application. Both are in the US east data center. Is it the same data center? i.e. do I need to pay for traffic between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same data center, so, no, you do not pay for bandwidth between them.  You would only pay for bandwidth down in other cases, and the first 5GB each month is free.